# position:fixed difference in IE Vs Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, modal-dialog

Lets say I have a main page which has a link that opens a modal div which has position:fixed and some width/height

Now I observe a behavior difference in IE Vs Firefox when this modal div is displayed i.e. ff we scroll the main window, 
In IE, the modal div also scrolls with the page;
While in Firefox, the scrolling of main window does not have any impact on the modal div and it literally remains fixed.

Is there any way by which we can have the modal div scroll in Firefox like in IE ?

Comment: Sounds like your IE doesn't support `position:fixed`, which version is it? According to http://caniuse.com/#search=fixed it must be IE6.

Comment: What tools if any are you using for your model dialog? Which versions of IE? Sample code?

Comment: I have IE8 on my system...So it does support position:fixed...In fact, I want Firefox to behave similar to IE..The modal div is actually a Thickbox window...But anyways, I think the main issue is the different behavior of using position:fixed

Comment: Including the following document type information may make the behavior consistent across browsers:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"> `

However, this isn't going to solve your issue of getting IE-like behavior in Firefox.  It may reveal, perhaps, that `position:fixed` is not what you want in this case.  IE is the one acting weird.

Comment: Tried that...But it does not help..

Comment: The simple sample code is required to better understand what you are doing and what you need. If "div" has 'style="position:fixed"', it must not scrolled with scroll of window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting Firefox to behave like you're saying IE is, and have the DIV scroll with the page, you shouldn't be using `position: fixed`. You want just `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Dalal - It's IE acting wronly.
position:fixed; means that an element is positioned with a certain x/y to your viewport, so of you want it to scroll with the page use position:absolute;

You may need to hack Thickbox in order to get this done.

Btw. Thickbox is a rather outdated lightbox variant. If you can, try to change to a newer one: http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/